# Primary key convention is not used

Tags: .net, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following Fluent NHibernate configuration:

```
var fluentConfig = Fluently.Configure()
.Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
    .ConnectionString(c => c
    .FromConnectionStringWithKey("TestPortalDbContext"))
)
.Mappings(m =>
    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>()
    .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<PrimaryKeyConvention>()
    .Conventions.Add<PrimaryKeyConvention>()
);
```

The problem is that the `PrimaryKeyConvention` is not used. Am I configuring it incorrectly?

**Update**

One of my mappings (generated by [NHibernate Mapping Generator](http://nmg.codeplex.com/))

```
public class TestResultMap : ClassMap<TestResult> {

    public TestResultMap() {
        Table("TestResults");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");
        References(x => x.TestSession).Column("SessionId");
        References(x => x.Instruction).Column("InstructionId");
        References(x => x.SolvedBy).Column("SolvedBy");
        Map(x => x.State).Column("StateId").CustomType<TestState>();
        Map(x => x.ActualResult).Column("ActualResult");
        Map(x => x.CompletedAt).Column("CompletedAt");
        Map(x => x.IsSolved).Not.Nullable().Column("IsSolved");
    }
}
```

**The error**

The error I get is that the key "ClassName_id" is not being found.

**The convention**

```
public class PrimaryKeyConvention
  : IIdConvention
{
    public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Column(instance.EntityType.Name + "Id");
    }
}
```

*It complains on the PK when looking up a related entity*

Comment: If you are using normal mappings (manually with `ClassMap<>`) do conventions even get used?  The only time I've used conventions is when I'm auto mapping.  If they do, then to me the config looks good.

Comment: I've added a mapping example.

Comment: I suspect your mapping is slightly off, it looks to me like you are explicitly giving your Id a column called 'Id' and then changing the configuration to try and look for something called 'TestResultId'.

Comment: conventions are also applied to fluentmappings but never override explicitly setted values like `.Column("Id")`, also `instance.EntityType.Name + "Id"` doesnt give you "ClassName_id" only ""ClassNameId". A stacktrace would help

Answer (score 0):

conventions are also applied to fluentmappings but never override explicitly setted values like `.Column("Id")`.